# Properties inherited by the coarse moduli space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-stacks

Let $\mathcal{X}$ be a regular, seperated Deligne-Mumford stack and $X$ be the coarse moduli scheme associated with $\mathcal{X}$. Then, is $X$ regular? I guess this is a basic fact but am not able to find any reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at all. Take for instance the quotient stack of $\mathbb{A}^2$ by $\pm 1$. The coarse moduli space is the quadratic cone.

Comment: Is there any known additional condition that we can impose on the stack to ensure that $X$ is regular?

Comment: If it is OK for you to think of the stack as of a global quotient stack by a finite group action, the condition is that the group is generated by complex reflections.

Comment: If $\mathcal{X}$ is one-dimensional, then $X$ is regular. If the coarse space map $\mathcal{X}\to X$ is etale, then $X$ is regular (and $\mathcal{X}\to X$ is a gerbe). If the stacky locus of $\mathcal{X}$ is pure of codimension one, then $X$ might be regular (I don't remember the precise statement).

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar I am new to the language of stacks. Could you suggest some reference where I can find your answer or Sasha's?

Comment: @Sasha Could you please suggest some reference for your comment.

Comment: @user43198: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chevalley%E2%80%93Shephard%E2%80%93Todd_theorem